# what are the Admob rewardedVideoAd error codes

Tags: java, android, admob

I try to load an admob rewarded video but each time when I try to show it jumps to the

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
    //LOG
}
```

function of the `RewardedVideoAdListener`. the `int i` is the error code according to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAdListener.html#onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int)). But there's no meaning to this number, the documentation does not specify e.g. what 1 means. Therefore my question, where can I find the individual meaning of each error code?

Comment: Have you followed the necessary steps to implement Admob? 
What is the flow that leads to the callback being triggered? I believe this is the proper place to look, [Admob's documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR). And [here](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603?hl=en)